# Pra que serve o "display: ruby" em CSS?

Tags: css

A pergunta é basicamente essa:

- Pra que serve o `display: ruby` em CSS?
- Esse atributo é novo?
- Quando usá-lo?

Comment: Pra mostrar código na linguagem lá no japonês :P :D

Comment: Quem negativou, pode dar um feedback?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`display:ruby` é o display padrão ta tag `<ruby>`. Assim como o display padrão da `<div>` é `block` e do `<span>` é `inline`.

O Chrome parece não usar `display:ruby` para a tag `<ruby>`, mas no FireFox vc já pode conferir que funciona. Apesar disso, a tag não é tão nova assim, e consta no  Working Draft da W3C desde 2014 como vc pode conferir no link oficial https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ruby-1/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> A anotação Ruby é uma forma de anotação interlinear, consistindo em pequenas sequências de texto ao lado do texto base. Eles são normalmente usados ​​em documentos do Leste Asiático para indicar pronúncia ou fornecer uma anotação curta.

Ou seja a tag `ruby` é usada como marcação de texto para indicar a pronuncia de algum texto em outro idioma, normalmente Asiáticos. Além disso, a tag não deve ser usada sozinha, ela deve ser usada em conjunto com as tags `<rp>` e `<rt>` para auxiliar na construção da marcação. Um elemento `<rp>` deve incluir cada um dos parênteses de abertura e fechamento que envolvem o elemento `<rt>`que contém o texto da anotação. O `<rp>` é opcional e ajuda a formatar o texto quando o navegador não tem suporte ao ruby.

Junto com a tag ruby vc pode usar também outras propriedade CSS como `ruby-align` e `ruby-position` para controlar como quer mostrar visualmente a anotação do texto. Aqui tem mais detalhes tecnicos https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Ruby

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o exemplo

```html
<ruby>
  漢 <rp>(</rp><rt>Kan</rt><rp>)</rp>
  字 <rp>(</rp><rt>ji</rt><rp>)</rp>
</ruby>
```

Outro exemplo, mais complexo um pouco e com duas anotações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<ruby>
  <ruby>東<rt>とう</rt>南<rt>なん</rt></ruby>
  <rt lang=en>Southeast</rt>
</ruby>
```

*Fonte:* https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-ruby-element

Atualmente segundo o CanIuse esse é o suporte dos navegadores https://caniuse.com/#feat=ruby

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá para usar esse display em outros elementos que não sejam o próprio ruby?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acredito que sim, da mesma forma que colocamos display:block na <img>, só não sei dizer como o elemento vai se comportar, até pq para ter a renderização como visto acima na resposta vc precisa também da tag <rt> e opcionalmente  da <rp> tb... e também tem o fator semântico da marcação... Se quiser algo similar visualmente acho que as vezes o <sup> pode ser melhor, já semanticamente talvez um simples <i> seja mais adequado...